# How to compare two files in java when the order of elements does'nt matter

Tags: java, file, compare

I want to compare 2 files and check that the contents are equals. But the problem is the data in the files are not in the same order. the equals() method returns me false even if the contents are equal when the elements are not placed in the same order. How can I compare these files in java by ignoring the order ? 
Best regards!

Comment: What do you mean by elements here? Lines?

Comment: It depends on the format your files: what makes it equal?

Comment: I think the best way is to get two files into two sets A and B, then you can do loads of stuff, e.g. checking set A and B contain same "String"

Comment: I mean, I have two csv files containing some elements. For example,  file1.csv contains A;B;C;D;E and file2.csv contains B;D;A;E;C. When I write file1.equals(file2), the code returns false because the order is not the same even if the contents are the same. So, my question is : how can I tell the program to ignore the order; just to check if the elements of file1.csv are in file2.csv. Thank you very much for your answers. (excuse my english ;) )

Comment: read data from file1 and file2 and store the string into Set<String> set1 and set2. then (set1.equals(set2)) will return you true if both contain the elements.

Comment: @nafas Thank you for your proposition. I tried it but I still have the same problem. this is my code : 
 String content1 = new Scanner(new File("C:/file1.txt")).next();
 String content2 = new Scanner(new File("C:/file2.txt")).next();
    System.out.println(st1.equals(st2)); 
The return is false ! I reminf that file1 contains A;B;C and file2 contains B;C;A

Comment: @Kazman Dude, do you know what set is? [set] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm). check this link then try to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code u want:

```
 Scanner input1= new Scanner(new File("C:/file1.txt");
 Scanner input2= new Scanner(new File("C:/file2.txt");
 String one= input1.nextLine();//assuming files contain only one line
 String two= input2.nextLine();//assuming files contain only one line
 Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(one.split(";"));
 Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(two.split(";"));

 System.out.println(set1.equals(set2));
```

Comment: Thank you @nafas ! This code works fine for one line. As my files contain more than one line, I used a while loop like this : 
while(input1.hasNext() && input2.hasNext()){
 // I implement your code
}
And I had the expected result. Thank you again

Comment: @Kazman I did mention the code only works for one line :). but I'm glad it works for u.

Answer (score 1):

Add all the elements to sets and compare the sets.  Note: sets will ignore duplicates.

Or you can sort all the elements and compare the results.  How you sort them doesn't matter provided the sorting it consistent. i.e. the original order doesn't change the result.  Use this if there are duplicates.

Comment: Thank you Peter :) I tried with set Collection that is supposed to ignore the order, but it does'nt work. This is my code :
String content1 = new Scanner(new File("C:/file1.txt")).next();
 String content2 = new Scanner(new File("C:/file2.txt")).next();
    System.out.println(st1.equals(st2)); 
The return is false ! I reminf that file1 contains A;B;C and file2 contains B;C;A

Comment: `but it does'nt work.` can you show how you tried to use the set?

Comment: Sorry Peter I forgot to write the entire code. But nafas gives me a good one but it work only for files containing just one line

Comment: @Kazman So change the code to read more than one line using a loop.

Comment: Yes I did it, and I had the expected result. Thank you for your help